# How to change border radius on click of the image in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

I have two Images. One is rectangle and another one is rounded corner Image. And one div is there. This div is a Square box.

1. If I click the rectangle Image, the square box border radius is 0px.
2. Same as if i click rounded corner, the square box border radius is 5px.

```js
rectangle():void{
document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0]["style"].borderRadius="0px";
}
roundedCorner():void{
document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0]["style"].borderRadius="5px";
}
```

```css
.square{
width:200px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img (click)="rectangle()" src="rectangleImage">
<img (click)="roundedCorner()" src="roundedCornerImage">

<div class="square"></div>
```

I tried this one. But it is not working for me. How can I do this in angular 2 or 4 or 5 or 6? Please help me anyone.

Comment: Your code seems to be working. where you stuck??

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: where your code is not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src = "assets/images/web423.jpg" (click)="borderradius='0px'" width="150px" height="150px"/>
<img src = "assets/images/web423.jpg" (click)="borderradius='5px'" width="150px" height="150px"/>

<div [ngStyle]="{'border-radius':borderradius}">Border Radius</div>
```

You can use [ngStyle] to change any style of the element.